# Expanding definition of simple graph isomorphism to include multigraphs

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I've defined isomorphism from one graph $G$ to another graph $K$ as follows:

An isomorphism is a bijective function $f$ from the vertices of $G$ to the vertices of $K$, such that the vertices $u$ and $v$ are neighbours in $G$ if and only if the vertices $f(u)$ and $f(v)$ are neighbours in $K$.

However, this definition only holds for simple graphs (graphs with no loops/parallel edges).

How can I change this definition to also include multigraphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I googled a bit for a definition of isomorphic mutigraphs, but found none. So I propose to naturally extend a notion of graph isomorphism to multigraphs as follows. For each multigraph $G$ with a vertex set $V$. For each $v,u\in V$ let $l(v)$ be the number of loops at vertex $v$ and $e(u,v)$ be the number of edges between $v$ and $u$. Then an isomorhism between multigraphs $G$ with a vertex set $V(G)$ and $H$ with a vertex set $V(H)$ is a bijection $f$ between $V(G)$ and $V(H)$ such that for each $v,u\in V$ holds $l(v)=l(f(v))$ and $e(u,v)=e(f(u),f(v))$.

Comment: Alternatively, an isomorphism might be defined as a map $V(G)\cup E(G)\to V(H)\cup E(H)$. That wouldn't affect the meaning of "isomorphic multigraphs" but it would make for a larger automorphism group for a graph with multiple edges, since you could permute edges while keeping the vertices fixed.

Comment: P. J. Cameronin in ["Automorphisms of Graphs"](http://vlsicad.eecs.umich.edu/BK/SAUCY/papers/Cameron2001.pdf) says: This simple definition does not suffice for multigraphs; we need to specify a permutation of the edges as well as a permutation of the vertices, to ensure that the multiplicity of edges between two vertices is preserved. (Alternatively, a multigraph can be regarded as a weighted graph [...] This gives a slightly different description of automorphisms,
but the action on the set of vertices is the same.) We will consider only simple graphs here.